# something like an integral but for fuzzy logic OR rather than summation

Tags: real-analysis, fuzzy-logic

I'm not well-versed in analysis.  I want to OR together an infinite number of fuzzy truths of infinitesimal significance.  I mean the following:

I have an arbitrary function $t(v)$ with a range on $[0,1]$ and a domain on, say, $[0,\ell]$.  There are many definitions of the fuzzy OR operator (co-norms), and I'm interested in many of them.  Here are some examples: $a \lor b = \max(a, b)$;  $a \lor b = a + b - ab$;  $a \lor b = (a + b) / (1 + ab)$;  $a \lor b = \min(a + b, 1)$.  Some have awkward conditions, like $a \lor b = \max(a, b)$ if $a + b < 1$ else $1$.$

The result should be at least as true as the truest point.  That is, if $t(v)$ is non-zero at only one point, the truth at that point is the result.  The longer $t(v)$ is non-zero, the truer it is.  That is, the OR-integral of a constant approaches $1$ as $\ell$ increases.  I don't know how fast it should approach $1$.  Perhaps, as $\ell$ approaches $\infty$, the or-integral of a constant approaches $1$ (I think so, but I'm not sure).  How the result depends on $\ell$, I don't know.  It must depend on the norm somehow.  (E.g., for the $\max$ definition of OR, not at all---the result would remain $\max\left(t(v)\right)$.)

I can think of three approaches.  First: by analogy to the product integral: transform the integrand into something that can be Riemann-integrated, then transform it back after integration.  @Karl has shown how to do this with the for $a + b - ab$: $\rm{OR}_0^\ell\, t(v)\, dv = 1−\prod_0^\ell\, (1−t(v))\, dv$.  It's not obvious to me how to do something like that for other norms.

Second:  numerically, or by analogy to ORing a finite number of discrete truths.  (This may be better after all, since I want to solve such problems numerically anyway.)  I mean:  If I sample $t(v)$ at many points $(v,t)$, I just OR all the $t$ together.  This seems highly dependent on the number of $t$.  I imagine that, for most norms and a lot of non-zero $t$, the result quickly approaches $1$.  I fear that, because of this, my results would almost always be $1$ or $0$, which would tell me nothing---it would throw away all the information in $t(v)$.

So, I'm thinking of an analogy to Riemann integration.  There, an infinite number of values are multiplied by an infinitesimal, reducing the significance of each.  Maybe I could reduce the significance of each $t$ under ORing in proportion to the number of $t$ being considered, the number of sample points.  (And, perhaps, take it to the limit of an infinite number of sample points of infinitesimal significance.)

The number $0$ is insignificant under ORing---ORing one constant and a million zeros results in the constant, for any norm, I think.  So, if I reduce all of the $t$ to nearly zero (in proportion to their population), and OR them all together, I might be on the right track.  But how exactly should I do this---by multiplying each, or taking each to a power, or by some other means---and how to do so without an underflow error if it's numerical?  And, how to do this without negating the effect that more  non-zero truths make the result truer?

Third:  what is wrong with the following?:
for the norm $a \lor b = a + b - ab$:

$$\rm{OR}_0^\ell\, t(v)\, dv = \int_0^\ell\,  t(v)\,  dv - \prod_0^\ell\,  t(v)\,  dv$$

where, by "$\prod$" I mean the product integral.

Comment: If you could first define a "weighted OR" operation on finitely many operands, then you could use it to define your integral-like operation in the manner of either Riemann or Lebesgue integration. But it's unclear how a weighted OR should be defined in terms of the unweighted OR. For example, you might want $f((a,\frac12),(b,\frac12))=f((a,\frac14),(a,\frac14),(b,\frac14),(b,\frac14))$, but in general $\operatorname{or}(a,b)$ and $\operatorname{or}(a,a,b,b)$ are different.

Comment: In your specific example, you have $\operatorname{or}(a_1,\dots,a_n)=1-\prod_{i=1}^n(1-a_i)$, so it could be reasonable to define $\operatorname{OR}_0^\ell t(v)dv=1-\prod_0^\ell(1-t(v))dv.$

Comment: I made up the notation in the first comment: the $a,b$ are fuzzy truth values and the $\frac12,\frac14$ are "desired weights". The unweighted OR doesn't generalize easily to "weighted combinations of inputs" because splitting $(a,\frac12)$ into $(a,\frac14),(a,\frac14)$ would seem to change the result.

Comment: For my second comment, notice that $a\lor b=a+b-ab=1-(1-a)(1-b).$ If you assume De Morgan's law with $\lnot x=1-x$ (which seems natural for these probability-like truth values), you obtain $a\land b=ab$, so your "AND integral" probably ought to be a product integral, and you can define the OR integral in terms of it.

Comment: To rephrase my first comment: If you have an arbitrary co-norm representing a symmetric OR operation, can you use it to define a related asymmetric OR operation that e.g. gives the first operand the "significance" of 1.5 operands and the second operand the "significance" of 0.5 operands? And what if the sum of the desired significances doesn't equal the number of operands? Figuring out a way to do this is the first step in figuring out how "to OR together an infinite number of fuzzy truths of infinitesimal significance" along the lines of how Lebesgue integrals are defined.

Comment: Thank you, Karl.  I would not assign different weights to different sample points.  Every point on $t(v)$ is equally significant.  I'm thinking of the way in which $dx$ in a Riemann integral weights every point in a function equally and infinitesimally.

Comment: You are correct in thinking that I use the standard *not* and that the *or* I presented is the dual of the product norm *and*.   I didn't recognize your re-written form of the *or* until you pointed it out to me.  The OR integral you describe makes sense to me now.  It's difficult to see how I could generalize this to other norms though.

Comment: How do you want the OR-integral to behave on a constant function? The finite OR depends on the number of operands even if they're all equal to each other, and the usual integral of a constant function depends on the length of the domain. So do you want the OR-integral from $0$ to $n$ of a constant $a$ to equal the $n$-fold OR of $a$ with itself?

Comment: ...Perhaps no, you expect the integral of a constant function to equal the constant value regardless of the length of the domain, like an average rather than a sum. But this amounts to assuming all the copies of $a$ "represent the same event", whereas the co-norm in a sense encodes an independence assumption about the events whose "probabilities" it operates on. I don't see how you can meaningfully incorporate a given co-norm while removing its dependence on the number of operands (but if you can, I think it involves weighting).

Comment: @Karl, thank you, you've given me a lot to think about and I've re-written the question.  I hope it is clearer now.